# Disable elastic scrolling inside a listview - react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to disable the elastic scrolling on top of the list view.
I'd like to have the upper edge of the picture "stuck" to the status bar.
Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes and no - it's possible for iOS where elastic behaviour is present. Check property `bounces` (boolean): https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#bounces-ios

Although it's under **ScrollView**, this property is inherited by **ListView** as well.